# How to get the value of an attribute in Javascript

Tags: javascript, getattribute

I have this input line which I am trying to extract the text of the value attribute:

```
    <input type="text" class="card-input small-font" 
ng-value="paymentVia.typeDisplay" readonly="" value="Credit card">
```

The function `getAttribute("class")` works fine and it returns `card-input small-font` but the function `getAttribute("value")` returns `null`. I tried .value as well but this returns an empty string.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

This is my JS:

```
function() {
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName("card-input small-font");
   var payment =x[18].value;

   return payment;
}
```

Comment: Show your html and your javascript.

Comment: Use `.value` property than `attribute..`

Comment: I added the html but it was removed from the question somehow :/ I'll try add it again. And I tried .value but it didn't work :/

Comment: @TamaraCaligari Function requires a name like: `function foo(){}` I don't see the name in your example.

Comment: @samayo The function is to create a custom variable for Google Tag Manager and we don't use function names. See here for examples: http://www.apasters.com/blog/google-tag-manager-custom-javascript-variable-examples/

Comment: @TamaraCaligari Please don't forget to accept the answer that has helped you.

Comment: var attribute = element.getAttribute(attributeName);

Answer (score 42):

[Node values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) and [Element Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) are different parts of an html tag.
So, you have to use `element.value` instead.

This is a an example, to show you how you can fetch `value`, `data`, `attribute` from an input field.

The HTML input field.

```
<input type="text" id="profile" data-nationality="Eritrean" value="Simon">
```

and the javascript.

```
var el = document.getElementById("profile"); 

console.log(el.value) // Simon
console.log(el.getAttribute("id")) // profile
console.log(el.dataset.nationality) // Eritrean
```

Comment: .value just returns an empty string for me :/

Comment: @TamaraCaligari Check maybe your `value` is empty.

Comment: In the console I get the correct response though. Not sure why it does not behave the same way in the function.

Comment: @TamaraCaligari I don't know about your case, but it works here https://jsfiddle.net/rqy9ddkj/

Answer (score 9):

`element.getAttribute("value")` returns value which was set in the markup, which is not necessarily same as `element.value`.

Also, value attribute of an element is only [synchronized one way](http://javascript.info/tutorial/attributes-and-custom-properties#value) - from markup to the object and vice versa doesn't happen.

So, if you want to get the value that is set programmatically, you need to write

```
element.value
```

else, if you need to get the value which was defined in the markup as

```
<input value="abc">
```

you need to do `element.getAttribute("value")`

Comment: As I mentioned in the other comment, element.value returns an empty string for me :/ Any ideas why?

Answer (score -3):

OR with jQuery you can get value from textbox like

```
var val1 = $(".class name").val();//to get value by class name
var val1 = $("#id").val();//to get value by id
```

Both will do same.

Regards