# how to pass @model.ApplicationId from html form to js

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am trying to make an auto save function that will save the form data. I am unable to pass my ApplicationId in from form to JS in order to auto save. Though with the fixed id, auto saving does work. I have the following code:

Js Code:

```
window.setInterval(AutoSaveDraft(id), 50000);



function AutoSaveDraft(id) {  
   $.post({
         url: "/Application/Edit/"+id ,
         data: $("#application-form").serialize()
         }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
      if (jqXhr.status === 200) {
          alert("Data Application has been saved");        
          return true;
       }
    });
}
```

Html CODE:

```
<form asp-action="Edit" id="application-form" name="@Model.ApplicationId" >
...
</form>
```

Basically, I want the @Model.ApplicationId to be passed to my Js, so that I can use that in my Autosaving function.

Comment: Do you want it sent via ajax? How do you want to use it?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I basically want to use it in my AutoSaveDraft(). So I just need id there.

Comment: `window.setInterval(AutoSaveDraft('@Model.ApplicationId'), 50000);` should work here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value of an attribute in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880165/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-attribute-in-javascript)

Comment: dbraillon-I have  a separate Js file so @Model.ApplicationId is not working. I tried using it.

Comment: Check my answer, it should works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have your JS on the same page as your html, you could simply write:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
   var id = '@Model.ApplicationId'; // Turned C# to JS here
   AutoSaveDraft(id);
}, 50000);

function AutoSaveDraft(id) {  
   $.post({
      url: "/Application/Edit/"+id ,
      data: $("#application-form").serialize()
   }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
      if (jqXhr.status === 200) {
          alert("Data Application has been saved");        
          return true;
       }
   });
}
```

Now let's say your JS is somewhere else:

HTML:

```
<form asp-action="Edit" id="application-form" name="@Model.ApplicationId" >
...
</form>
```

JS:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
   var id = $("#application-form").attr('name'); // Retrieve the ID
   AutoSaveDraft(id);
}, 50000);

function AutoSaveDraft(id) {  
   $.post({
      url: "/Application/Edit/"+id ,
      data: $("#application-form").serialize()
   }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
      if (jqXhr.status === 200) {
          alert("Data Application has been saved");        
          return true;
       }
   });
}
```

That's said, I would suggest you to use `data-` attribute to pass that kind of data. Let's try with `data-application-id`.

```
<form asp-action="Edit" id="application-form" data-application-id="@Model.ApplicationId">
...
</form>

window.setInterval(function () {
   var id = $("#application-form").data("application-id"); // Retrieve here
   AutoSaveDraft(id);
}, 50000);
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, your interval is wrong. What you are doing is calling a function and passing the result to the interval. You need to pass it a function that it can then call when needed. You are calling your function right away.

Next, all you need to do, is to use jQueries `attr()` method like so:

```js
let id = 'application-form'
window.setInterval(() => AutoSaveDraft(id), 5000);

function AutoSaveDraft(id) {
  let name = $(`#${id}`).attr('name')
  console.log(name)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form asp-action="Edit" id="application-form" name="@Model.ApplicationId">

</form>
```

Comment: OP isn't using the id variable as you do, he needs to get an id from it's Model and to use it to build the url in ajax request.

Comment: My question asked how it was to be used, the answer was that they just want access to it, which is how I answered.

Comment: GetOffMyLawn- It didn't work for me. I tried . Is there any other way in which I can use the @Model.ApplicationId in Js?

Comment: In which way did it not work? If you run the code, you will see that it is getting the value. More information would be helpful.