# Getting data from text file via data-src using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to retrieve text from a .txt file using jQuery (I am also using Bootstrap). I am very new to web design but I am familiar somewhat with coding. I have the following button in my HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline-btn text-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-src="test.txt" data-target="#textModal"><img class="video_icon" src="assets/icons/parchment_icon.png" alt="text"</button>
```

As you can see, the target of the button is a modal which loads up text like so:

```
<!-- Text Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="textModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p id="outputText">File not found.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

My JS file looks like this (changed following one of the answers):

```
$(".text-btn").on("click", textFunction);

function textFunction() {
  var el = document.getElementById('test');
  console.log(el.getAttribute('data-src'));
  jQuery.get(el.getAttribute('data-src'), function(data) {
    $( '#outputText' ).html(data.replace('n',''));
  });
}
```

Whilst the filepath outputs to the console correctly, I am unsure how to use jQuery to utilise this so that it will input the file contents into the modal-body. Additionally, my issue is now how to make the variable assigned through `getElementById` correctly correspond to the button pressed. Moreover, I am not sure how to use `getAttribute` or `attr` in jQuery to obtain the data source in javascript.

This is an issue as I will have multiple buttons with multiple file sources so I would like the jQuery to retrieve from each button's respective data source. Is there a way in which I can do this...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value of an attribute in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880165/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-attribute-in-javascript)

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey. Thank you for your reply but I think not as it appears the values passed in are strings and I am hoping to retrieve data from a text file. I may be incorrect but I was led to believe this entails a slightly different process?

Comment: You're looking to get the value of `data-src` attribute into the URL argument of the `jQuery.get` call, right? The linked question's answers describe how to get the value of the `data-src` attribute, just as both of the current answers do.

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey. Perhaps I misunderstood. Just to be clear, is the value of ```data-src``` when put into jQuery.get equivalent to ```jQuery.get('test.txt' ... );```? I am trying to get the text from test.txt into the ```modal-body```. With respect to the current answers you refer to, do you mean the ones below? Unfortunately I keep pulling the entire page source instead of just the data-src value. I will attempt again with this change and report back.

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey. Thanks so much. You were correct. It logs the file path to the console when I have ```console.log(el.getAttribute('data-src'))```. For the jQuery.get, I am not sure how to formulate this as ```jQuery.get($(el.getAttribute('data-src')) ... );``` does not work. Apologies for the questions.

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey. My apologies for the triple post. I have now amended the OP to reflect changes but unfortunately still a little ways off from the answer although it does successfully output the console. I think it's a syntax issue, owing to my lack of knowledge with respect to jQuery. Thank you for your help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the full file url in data-src then use:

```js
$('.text-btn').on('click', function() {
    $.get($(this).data('src'), function(data) {
        $('#outputText').html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Ibrahim El Hajj. Thank you for your reply. I have this set currently as test.txt is in the same directory as index.html. Would I still need to make it explicit?

Comment: Hi @jsaider, this will work for you but we use the full url to avoid any broken ones cause I usually use frameworks and url will be relative to the route

Comment: Hi @Ibrahim El Hajj. I attempted with the full URL and I got a CORS issue (I am running the site via Github pages currently). I then removed the URL and simply used the filepath but this also did not work and gave me a 404 error.

Comment: Hi @Ibrahim El Hajj. My apologies. I made some changes (so as the file is the same directory, I simply point to the filename itself) and it works. Thank you so much. I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of multiple buttons, you can use an `onclick` event on each, which will fire `textFunction`. Then, inside the text function, you can retrieve the correct button's `data-src` using jQuery's `data()` function:

```
//assuming all your relevant buttons have class `text-btn`
//call textFunction on button click
$(".text-btn").on("click", textFunction);

function textFunction() {
  //inside event handler, `this` points to the button that triggered the event
  jQuery.get($(this).data('src'), function(data) {
    alert(data);
    $( '#outputText' ).html(data.replace('n',''));
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Anis R. I attempted this but I seem to be getting the entire source code for the webpage here. I tried both removing and including the call to the function in ```$document.ready``` but to no avail, unfortunately.